# Pass Image to another function within same class

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, popupwindow

I've been searching for a solution for three days now.
If everyone has an Idea please help me, I don't even think it's actually that difficult to achieve but It's not really my branch, if you can say it like this.

In a RecyclerView containing a list with multiple Items, each having a Title(TextView) and a Cover image(ImageView).

This data is set in the Adapter, in the ViewHolder, more specifically in the `OnBind` function.

So where's my problem?
I've created a PopUp Window, which contains besides a few buttons, a placeholder ImageView and a placeholder TextView.
I cannot seem to find a way to place the data of the clicked Item in the list inside the placeholders.
I think it's similar to the OnBind method but it doesn't work.

Here's the Adapter (if the code for GameItem is needed I'll gladly post it):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameViewAdapter.GameViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<GameItem> mGameList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onGameClick(int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener =listener;
    }
    public static class GameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView Cover;
        public TextView Title;
        public TextView Description;
        public PopupWindow popupWindow;
        public ImageView popUpImage;
        public TextView PopUpTitle;
        public EditText customAmount;
        public Button add;
        private Button addcustom;
        private  Button exit;

        public GameViewHolder(final View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addaverage);
            addcustom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addcustom);
            popUpImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.popupimg);
            PopUpTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.popuptitle);
            customAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gameamount);
            Cover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.GameCover);
            Title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.GameTitle);
            Description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.GameAmount);
            exit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exit);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showPopUp();
                }
            });
        }

        public void showPopUp() {
            final View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(itemView.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            exit = popupView.findViewById(R.id.exit);
            exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        }
    }

    public GameViewAdapter(ArrayList<GameItem> gameList){
        mGameList = gameList;
    }





    @Override
    public GameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.game_entry, viewGroup, false);
        GameViewHolder GVH = new GameViewHolder(v, mListener);
        return GVH;
    }


        @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameViewHolder gameViewHolder, int position){
        GameItem currentItem = mGameList.get(position);
        Glide.with(gameViewHolder.Cover).load(currentItem.getCover()).into(gameViewHolder.Cover);
        gameViewHolder.Title.setText(currentItem.getTitle());
        gameViewHolder.Description.setText(currentItem.getDescription());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mGameList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to understand what is exactly your problem... The images and the text won't show after binding? Could you explain that? Please

Comment: In the `OnBind` method, the Image and Text are associated to the Items correctly, through Glide and `gameViewHolder.Title.setText(currentItem.getTitle());`.
Now, I have created a PopUp, which should get the Image and the Text from the clicked item in the RecyclerView

Comment: I tried to do get the single Item through `getAdapterPosition` or something but I failed, and cannot find a way to use the method `getCover`, defined in the `GameItem` class in my `showPopUp()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the OnBind method, the Image and Text are associated to the Items
>   correctly, through Glide and
>   gameViewHolder.Title.setText(currentItem.getTitle());. Now, I have
>   created a PopUp, which should get the Image and the Text from the
>   clicked item in the RecyclerView.

I've reordered some methods and properties for the sake of clarity and then next, I'll explain.

```
public class GameViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameViewAdapter.GameViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<GameItem> mGameList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public GameViewAdapter(ArrayList<GameItem> mGameList, GameViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener mListener) {
        this.mGameList = mGameList;
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    @Override
    public GameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.game_entry, viewGroup, false);
        GameViewHolder GVH = new GameViewHolder(v, mListener);
        return GVH;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameViewHolder gameViewHolder, int position){
        gameViewHolder.bind(mGameList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mGameList.size();
    }

    class GameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView itemCover;
        private TextView itemTitle;
        private TextView itemDescription;
        private PopupWindow popupWindow;
        private ImageView popUpImage;
        private TextView PopUpTitle;
        private EditText customAmount;
        private Button add;
        private Button addcustom;
        private Button exit;

        public GameViewHolder(View itemView, GameViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener mListener) {
            super(itemView);
            setupViews(itemView);
        }

        public void bind(GameItem gameItem) {
            Glide.with(this.itemCover).load(gameItem.getCover()).into(this.itemCover);
            this.itemTitle.setText(gameItem.getTitle());
            this.itemDescription.setText(gameItem.getDescription());
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showPopUp(itemView, gameItem);
                }
            });
        }

        private void setupViews(View itemView) {
            add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addaverage);
            addcustom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addcustom);
            popUpImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.popupimg);
            PopUpTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.popuptitle);
            customAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gameamount);
            itemCover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.GameCover);
            itemTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.GameTitle);
            itemDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.GameAmount);
            exit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exit);
        }

        private void showPopUp(View itemView, GameItem gameItem) {
            final View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(itemView.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            final ImageView popupItemCover = popupView.findViewById(R.id.popupItemCover);
            final TextView popupItemTitle = popupView.findViewById(R.id.popupItemTitle);

            Glide.with(popupItemCover).load(gameItem.getCover()).into(popupItemCover);
            popupItemTitle.setText(gameItem.getTitle());

            exit = popupView.findViewById(R.id.exit);
            exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onGameClick(int position);
    }
}
```

What changed? 
First, we now have a method called `bind` inside our `ViewHolder`, we took the responsibility from setting the data from our `Adapter` and delegated it to the `ViewHolder`.
Second, as that method is called every time `onBindViewHolder` is called, you'll have the actual `GameItem`. So? With that item, instead of setting the `onClickListener` to open the PopUp in the `GameViewHolder`constructor, we now set it in the `bind` method. But, what are the benefits from it? Every time we bind data to its views, we prepare our `Popup` and then show it.

What should be changed?
For performance purposes, I guess, you should instantiate the constructor and then populate it every time with new data, instead of creating a new instance again every time `onBindViewHolder` is called.

Edit: As I don't know your popup views IDs, I've created some dummies IDs. Hope you understand.

Best.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, many people just paste the correct code, you instead went on to explain it as well! The Code works perfectly, only thing that I have to change then is, in the Main Activity, to add the Clicklistener as parameter, done that and now it works!!

If you don't know what I mean:
`GameListAdapter = new GameViewAdapter(GameList, (GameViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener) GameViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener);` looked like
`GameListAdapter = new GameViewAdapter(GameList`

Comment: You're welcome, mate. Feel free to ask if you have any other doubts